# How to use getHours() and getMinutes() method in API 15?

Tags: java, android, timepicker

My minimum SDK version is 15 and max is 23.

According to google documentation now we have to use `getMinute()` and `getHour()` method.

But it's only working in api 23. what we have to do for other API?

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As getHours(), getMinutes() and getSeconds() are all deprecated in Java and they are replaced with Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND.

Try this :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourdate);
int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: i am asking for android. in android getCurrentHour and getCurrentMinute are deprecated for api level 23. for api level 23 getHour and getMinute methods are used..so  How to use getHours() and getMinutes() method in API between 15 and 23 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding one timepicker and one button on its layout file:-

`timePick=(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        set=(Button) findViewById(R.id.butt);`

```
    set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calNow=Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePick.getCurrentHour());
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePick.getCurrentMinute());});
```